# How to rename data frame column by taking only the first value of the splitter string

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(n.foldchange = c(2, 3, 5), s.foldchange = c(4, 
0.2, 100.3)), .Names = c("n.foldchange", "s.foldchange"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this:

```
  n.foldchange s.foldchange
1            2          4.0
2            3          0.2
3            5        100.3
```

What I want to do is to rename the column by removing the value after `.`.
Yielding

```
             n            s
1            2          4.0
2            3          0.2
3            5        100.3
```

How can I do that? (with [`tidyverse`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/index.html) possible?)

Answer (score 2):

We can rename the `names` of columns using `setnames` with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 setnames(sub("\\..*", "", names(.)))

df

#  n     s
#1 2   4.0
#2 3   0.2
#3 5 100.3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `sub` to match the `.` (escape the `.` (`\\.`) to get the literal meaning of `.` as it is a metacharacter which means any character) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with blanks

```
names(df) <- sub("\\..*", "", names(df))
```

---

Or using `substring` or `substr`

```
names(df) <- substring(names(df), 1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution uses base R functions `substring` and `regexpr`.

```
names(df) <- substring(names(df), 1, regexpr(".", names(df), fixed=TRUE)-1)

df
  n     s
1 2   4.0
2 3   0.2
3 5 100.3
```

Here, `regexpr` is used to identify the positions of the first dot in the variable names. This position (minus one) is given to `substring` which returns a substring of the original variable names starting at the first character and ending right before the first dot.